# Meaning of - "smaller planes have now given way to bigger planes"

Tags: sentence-meaning, american-english

Can you please explain the meaning of planes in the below sentence?

Over the years, smaller planes have now given way to bigger planes. Air travel is expensive but the number of people travelling by air and the airlines have increased.

I tried to search on google and found below but seems like that is not relevant in above context. Can you please suggest?

[image]

Comment: *plane* is a short way of saying *airplane*.

Comment: Or aeroplane if you are in the British English part of the world. Aircraft is also very common.

Comment: Can we assume you understand the "have now given way" part?

Answer (score 4):

Egads. Try a [real dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/plane).

Or, do you see that chevron that says "more definitions"? Had you clicked on that, you would have seen:

[image]

Comment: Not to mention [*plane*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plane): "1. A **plane** is a vehicle with wings and one or more engines, which can fly through the air." It's pretty clear.